# Does setting the FIPS mode change the signature in OpenSSL?

Tags: c#, .net, openssl, bouncycastle

I think this is a stupid question, but... does calling FIPS_mode_set(1) in OpenSSL actually change the signature that I am going to get back, and if so, if I am trying to do the equivalent in bouncycastle/.NET, is there anything I need to do?

Background: I don't actually really care about FIPS at all for the purpose of what I am doing, I am just trying to get a C#.NET implementation that produces a signature that matches an existing OpenSSL implementation.  What the existing code is doing, by my reading of it, is computing a SHA256 hash, then applying a private RSA key from a .pem file.  It's using the EVP_Sign* functions to do it.  I tried to do the equivalent using System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256 to generate the hash, and bouncycastle's PemReader, AsymmetricCypherKeyPair, RsaEngine, and Pkcs1Encoding classes... but my output is not matching.

The OpenSSL implementation calls FIPS_mode_set(1), and that's the only thing I feel like I haven't accounted for... by my reading, all that does is make it so it will barf if you using anything that is not certified FIPS compliant, i.e. it shouldn't change the output of the signature.  But I've got this nagging feeling...

Oh, and PKCS1 is the right encoding to use to match what OpenSSL does with an EVP_SignFinal, right?

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please.

Comment: No, setting FIPS mode will not change the signature.

Comment: Can't really do an example because a) some of the real code is not public so no dice, and b) if I could make a self-contained example, then I wouldn't have this problem :p  Anyway, indiv seems to have answered my question.